# Filtering and adding class attribute in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

How would I do this in mootools? I have an Unordered list items that I want to add classes to each of them But there are some list item that I want to exclude in adding a new class.

here's my markup

```
<div id="header">
     <ul id="mainnav">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="item3"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

here's something I want to achieve using mootools

```
<div id="header">
     <ul id="mainnav">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="item3 NewClass"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="item4 NewClass"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the second `item4` is `item5`, ( though I'm a jQuery user ) but a quick look at the API says it should be like this:

```
$$('.item3', '.item5').addClass('newClass')
```

Comment: THANK YOU meder, this answer to my question. :)

Comment: don't forget to click on the big check box if someone answers your question :)